# How to set DNNArticle tabbed to show articles by categories

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have installed module DNNArticle and ArticleTabbed to show each article by category, how to do it?

I know to create articles but when click in readmore button show empty page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably get better support from the module creator, zldnn.com.